# Does Google-Colab continue running the script when "Runtime disconnected"?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am training a neural network for Neural Machine Traslation on Google Colaboratory. I know that the limit before disconnection is 12 hrs, but I am frequently disconnected before (4 or 6 hrs). The amount of time required for the training is more then 12 hrs, so I add some savings each 5000 epochs.

**I don't understand if when I am disconnected from Runtime (GPU is used) the code is still execute by Google on the VM?** I ask it because I can easily save the intermediate models on Drive, and so continue the train also if I am disconnected.

Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for ~1.5 hours after you close the browser window. 
To keep things running longer, you'll need an active tab.

Comment: What do you mean for *active tab*? In my case I have still open the Colab tab with the pop-up message "Runtime disconnected". Does it allow me to keep things running for more than 1.5 hrs?

Comment: An active tab is one that is connected and has recent executed a code cell. (The idle timeout only applies if no code is executing.)

Comment: Ok great, so basically I can wait more or less 1.5 hrs after the "Runtime disconnection" and then I have to reconnect, otherwise it will be a waste of time? In my case the problem is that the running cell is just one (the one in which the training starts) and then I cannot send more commands. Any idea on how to seems alive to Google?

Comment: I have not tried myself, but you could use multiprocessing to launch a Process that runs the training function in the background. Then you are free to run other commands (i.e., run cells) in the foreground

Comment: I have the same issue and would like to ask if it still worked, after the pop up message: Runtime disconnected